# Invalid command 'AuthAuthoritative'

Tags: apache-httpd

I'm trying to start the Apache2 server but I get this error:

```
Invalid command 'AuthAuthoritative', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server...iguration
```

This is the config in `httpd.conf` :

```
AllowOverride           all

Satisfy                 any

AuthAuthoritative       on
AuthUserFile            /home/netmet/netMet/etc/apache.passwd
AuthGroupFile           /home/netmet/netMet/etc/apache.group
AuthName                "netMET access's"
AuthType                Basic
require                 group netmet netmet-cgi

order                   deny,allow
deny from               all
allow from              host.domain.fr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to load `mod_auth`. If you use some distribution that has `a2enmod`, it is just `a2enmod auth`.

Comment: I tried and `ERROR: Module mod_auth does not exist!`

Comment: @alex It's just `a2enmod auth`, generally.

Comment: @MichaelHomer same result `ERROR: Module auth does not exist!`

Comment: Sorry about that, too long since I've done anything with a2enmod.

Comment: Then you need to install that module, your distribution probably has it in some package.

Comment: Modern Apache has [a whole family of `auth` modules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html), so you'll need to pick one (and I'm not sure that `AuthAuthoritative` is part of any of them any more - you may want `AuthBasicAuthoritative` from `mod_auth_basic`, but you're clearly following documentation that doesn't match the system you're using, so **check that you're making the settings you actually want**).